# The sum over inverses of n positive real numbers, which is less or equal 1, yields a convex set

Tags: convex-geometry

Is the set

$\left\{(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)\in\mathbb{R}_{\geq 1}^n:\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{x_i}\leq 1\right\}$

convex? For $n=2$ it is not too difficult to show convexity and I guess one has to find the right transformations to avoid messy computations. I am thankful for suggestions how to solve this or where in the literature I could find the solution.

While reading about convexity today, i also came across the inequality Max Alekseyev mentioned in his answer (I wasn`t aware of it before). I found some other results and I guess it can also be proven somewhat similar to Pietro Majers comment. It can be shown that the function

$f(x)=\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{x_i}\right)^{-1}$

is concave ($x\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}^n$). So the hypograph

$H_f=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}^n\times\mathbb{R}:y\leq f(x)\}$

is a convex set. Then

$H_f\cap\{(x,1):x\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}^n\}$

is convex and so is the projection of this set onto the first $n$ coordinates. This last set was the set from the question.

Comment: Am I missing something? $\mathbb{R}_+\ni t \mapsto1/t $ is a convex function; sum of convex functions is a convex function; the sublevel set of a convex function is a convex set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let
$$X = \left\{(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)\in\mathbb{R}_{\geq 1}^n:\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{x_i}\leq 1\right\}.$$

To prove that $X$ is convex, it is enough to show that 
$$\alpha\cdot x+(1-\alpha)\cdot y\in X$$
for any $x,y\in X$ and any real $\alpha\in[0,1]$.

Denote $\beta=1-\alpha$. We have $\beta\in[0,1]$ as well. It is clear that
$$\alpha\cdot x+\beta\cdot y = (\alpha\cdot x_1+\beta\cdot y_1, \dots, \alpha\cdot x_n+\beta\cdot y_n)$$
and we need to show that the sum of reciprocals of these components is at most 1. For any $i=1,2,\dots,n$, we have
$$\frac{1}{\alpha\cdot x_i+\beta\cdot y_i} \le \alpha\frac{1}{x_i}+\beta\frac{1}{y_i}$$
as the inequality between [weighted harmonic and arithmetic means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean) of $\frac{1}{x_i}$ and $\frac{1}{y_i}$ with the weights $\alpha$ and $\beta$, respectively. Summing up over $i$, we get
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{\alpha\cdot x_i+\beta\cdot y_i} \le \alpha\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{x_i}+\beta\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{y_i} \le \alpha + \beta =1$$
as required.

Comment: Thank you very much, that is what I need. I found a different approach in the library today (I hope the arguments hold), which uses a lot more machinery than the mentioned inequality.